# Faster Way to remove users from a huge list of groups?

Tags: powershell

I run the following code to remove disabled users from a list of 9874 groups:

```
 $user = get-aduser <userid> -Server "<server from another domain>"

 foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Write-Host "Removing $user from $group" -Foreground Green
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -Confirm:$false
}
```

It's a bottle neck for me as it checks/removes the account from each group.  Is there a way to speed this up with more efficient PS code?

Comment: Way to improve speed use **runspacepool**, or get PS version 7 and use  `ForEach-Object -Parallel`

Comment: Also avoid writing anything to the console, that slows things down too.

Comment: Is the list of users small? Maybe you can consider using `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` to remove a bunch of groups from a smaller set of users. Also `-Members` takes an array of users, so you ***can*** reduce the number of `Remove-ADGroupMember` calls.

Comment: I like seeing the progress on the console to see whether it's close to being finished.

Comment: I don't know how many users total.  I'm running one script to find disabled accounts in a group, then running this script to remove the disabled accounts I've found from a list of all groups from a particular OU.  I'm doing it this was because we have multiple domains and one-way trusts, so it's too complex to do it all in one script.

Answer (score 0):

If memberOf is the only thing are you interested in for a given user, you can run the following. It only loads the memberOf property and removes the user from each of these. Gives you a bit of a performance boost since its not loading all the account properties.

```
Get-ADUser <userid> -Server "<server from another domain>" -Properties MemberOf `
    | Select -Expand MemberOf | % { 
        Remove-ADGroupMember $_ -member <userid>"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't work.  I think it's due to the fact that the account and the security groups are in two different domains.

Comment: @DanielGower you can add the -Server switch to Remove-ADGroupMember as well.